# How can I capture a variable inside a while loop, with ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, while-loop

I have a loop to answer questions that looks something like this:

```
<?php
while ($u=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>     
<table>
 <tr>
     <td>Question_ID</td>
     <td>Question</td>
     <td>Answer</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td><? echo $u['question_id'];?></td>
     <td><? echo $u['question'];?></td> 
     <td> 
         <form>
         <input type="hidden" value="echo $u['question_id'];?>" />
         <input type="text"/>
         <a href="#" onClick="ajax_answer();">Send Answer</a>
         </form>
     </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<?php
} 
?>
```

If the user answers for example the third question that appears on the page, my question is how do I capture the text written and the question_id so I can send those variables to a php page?

```
<script>
   function ajax_answer(){
       $.ajax({
       question_id = ??? //how do I capture this variable?
       answer = ??? //how do I capture this variable?
       url:'answers.php',
       type:'POST',
       dataType:'text/html',
       data:'question_id='+question_id + '&answer='+answer,
       success: function(){
                          };
             });
       };
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: It would be easier if you added an `id` attribute to the elements and then use the domelement using javascripts' `getElementById` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in pure javascript,
then pass `this` to your `ajax_answer` function from `onclick` event like below

```
<?php
  while( $u = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
?> 
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $u['question_id'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $u['question'];?></td> 
    <td>
      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $u['question_id'];?>" />
      <input type="text" />
      <a href="#" onclick="ajax_answer( this );">Send Answer</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php
  }
?>
```

and your javascript will be...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function ajax_answer( elem ) {
    var question_id = elem.parentElement.children[0].value;
    var answer      = elem.parentElement.children[1].value;

    /// do your request here

    return false;
  }
</script>
```

And the same with jQuery.
Add `name` attribute to those input elements, and add a `classname` to `anchor` element

```
<?php
  while( $u = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
?> 
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $u['question_id'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $u['question'];?></td> 
    <td>
      <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="<?php echo $u['question_id'];?>" />
      <input type="text" name="answer" />
      <a href="#" class="send_answer">Send Answer</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php
  }
?>
```

**Javascript**
add the `onclick` event handler dynamically. Now your function `ajax_answer` accepts two parameters `question_id` and `answer`, we will pass those two parameters through the `click` event handler

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("a.send_answer").on("click", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var td  = $(this).parents("td:first");
      var qid = $("input[name=question_id]", td).val();
      var ans = $("input[name=answer]", td).val();

      ajax_answer( qid, ans );
    });
  });
  function ajax_answer( question_id, answer ) {
    /// do your request here
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not giving them an id. I would give the a tag an id with a prefix so that you can use the same id to get your related input value:

```
<a href="#" id="q<php echo $u['question_id'];?>" // note that I added a "q" prefix
```

Then you should be able to get that via jQuery like this:

```
var theid = $(this).attr('id'); // this being the a tag that was clicked

// then just strip off the leading "q" and you have your id.
var thehiddenid = theid.replace('q', '');
```

Comment: Ok, but how do I get the text written on the input field?

Comment: Same thing, you need to give your HTML elements a unique id so that you can reference them by that id later. If you want to you can use the same question number and just prefix it with a "t" or something.

Answer (score 0):

You change your form and add `id` for easier selection:

```
     <form>
     <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $u['question_id'];?>" id="question_id" />
     <input type="text"/>
     <a href="#" onClick="ajax_answer();">Send Answer</a>
     </form>
```

Then get the values like this:

```
  question_id = $("#question_id").val();
```

Or if your form has only one hidden field for question_id:

```
question_id = $("input[type=hidden]").val();
```

Note: please consider to use `<?php` tags not short tags `<?`

Comment: your html doesn't have an opening php tag `<?php` or `<?`

Comment: this is another issue.

Comment: Ofcourse I am just saying its a typo .. dont worry no downvotes bro chill lol :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but the form is inside a loop, so I may have lot of forms and so, a lot of Ids. How do I call the correct id?